# ASP.NET Routing webform query

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a ASP.net Web forms project that I am working on.
I need to have a add club page where the admin can add a club to the website.

When the club is added it creates a small website within my website for that club automatically. I think this uses some form of string builder.

Then that club should be able to store their own details on that page.

I was going to do this doing asp.net routing. Would this be the correct way of going about this?

Having looked at different examples i would need to have the url for the webpage automatically generated

Comment: To clarify, does this mean you want the name of the club to be part of the URL? So if admin creates a club called "spades", you want to have a URL like www.site.com/clubs/spades/[section for this club]?

Comment: Does not have to the same name of the club. There is a similar website that i have seen and it uses a unique number for each club.

Comment: Say for example /Clubs/Listing/"number for club"

Comment: Anyone any ideas on how i would go about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you are using asp.net 4.0.. something like this

Global.asax.cs

```
    protected void Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    protected virtual void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
        routes.MapPageRoute("clubs"
        , "clubs/listing//{clubNumber}"
            , "~/Clubs/ManageClub.aspx");
    }
```

so urls like /Clubs/Listing/ClubNum101 would resolve to /Clubs/ManageClub.aspx

In ManageClub.aspx check for RouteData e.g.

```
if (Page.RouteData != null && Page.RouteData.Values.ContainsKey("clubNumber")) {
    //do something here
}
```